Full cone NAT in Kubernetes
How to achieve full cone NAT connectivity inside k8s pods?
I've tested NAT on EC2 (without k8s):
% pystun3
NAT Type: Full Cone

Different story inside pods:
% kubectl run natdisco --rm -i --tty --image=yarmak/natdisco --restart=Never
NAT Type: Symmetric

I'm on EKS.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sure thing. I've put the question in bold.
